# Assembly not moving to bin folder in Visual Studio C# 2010 project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll

I have a question about references in Visual Studio 2010 (c#). I've just added a required DLL (one that I've gotten from a 3rd party API) to my class library project and when I add the class library project to my cmd application, the dll doesn't move to the bin folder of the cmd app. I've done a full clean and rebuild of the solution but it doesn't seem to help. When I run the cmd program, I get the exception, cannot load assembly (file is missing), which is the expected error. All the other dlls that are linked to the class library are in the bin folder; only the new one is missing.

Any ideas?

Comment: You have to select that dll file (in project tree) and set its properties. There is a property which cant be set to "Always Copy" or "Copy always". Try this and give feedback if it works.

Comment: The property CopyLocal is set to 'true' just like all the other assemblies. There's no difference in the properties page when comparing against the other dlls I'm including.

Answer (score 0):

Are you adding a reference to the compiled class library DLL, or a reference to the entire class library project? If it's the first, Visual Studio can't tell *another* DLL is required.

The second might work, although I'm not sure.

Comment: I'm referencing the assembly to the actual class library project, then I add the class library project as a reference to the console app. What's strange is that the other assemblies do appear in the bin of the console app, but only the new one does not.

Comment: Ok, here's the deal. Because the class library was not using the dll directly (not using any of its methods), the dll was not being moved to the console app's bin directory. So what I had to do is add the reference to the console app even though that app doesn't use any of the methods. But what the console app does do is load the config (via xml) for the 3rd part API that requires that dll.

Ugh!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here's the deal. Because the class library was not using the dll directly (not using any of its methods), the dll was not being moved to the console app's bin directory. So what I had to do is add the reference to the console app even though that app doesn't use any of the methods. But what the console app does do is load the config (via xml) for the 3rd party API that requires that dll. Ugh!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have got some Anti-Virus on your computer that makes this pain...
try to turn it off and then retry attaching the DLL

if it's the problem, then Google for what other people did regarding your specific
anti-virus (and OS version)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the appropriate references have been made, if you're using 3rd party software that gets installed on your machine, then when including a reference to one of it's DLLs, the reference may have it's *Copy Local* property set to *False*.  If so, you will need to set it to *True*.